# Login modal window comes over the home page automatically when user visit to website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have code below which trigger login modal on click the link on home page. i want it to be trigger automatically on load of home page.

HTML

```
<center><a href="#loginmodal" class="flatbtn" id="modaltrigger">Modal Login</a>      </center>
   <div id="loginmodal" style="display:none;">
     <h1>User Login</h1>
     <form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="post" action="index.html">
       <label for="username">Username:</label>
       <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="txtfield" tabindex="1">

       <label for="password">Password:</label>
       <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="txtfield" tabindex="2">
       <div class="center"><input type="submit" name="loginbtn" id="loginbtn"            class="flatbtn-blu hidemodal" value="Log In" tabindex="3"></div>
     </form>
   </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#loginform').submit(function(e){
       return false;
    });

    $('#modaltrigger').leanModal({ top: 110, overlay: 0.45, closeButton: ".hidemodal" });
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this snippet. **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nn5KU/)**

```
$(function(){
    $('#loginform').submit(function(e){
        return false;
    });

    $('#modaltrigger').leanModal({ top: 110, overlay: 0.45, closeButton: ".hidemodal" });
    $('#modaltrigger').trigger('click');
});
```

Use jQuery **[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** to manually trigger a click event on an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript setTimeout method to load the modal window on page laod with a small time like 10ms.

```
$(function(){
$('#loginform').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
 });
    setTimeout(function(){
     $('#modaltrigger').trigger('click');
    },10);

 $('#modaltrigger').leanModal({ top: 110, overlay: 0.45, closeButton: ".hidemodal" });
});
```

please see this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/lokeshpahal/3vLdp/